# how to assign ng2 smart table settings property

Tags: angular

I followed the link https://akveo.github.io/ng2-smart-table/#/demo
to generate table in angular2. problem i am facing is I am not able to assing value to settings variable dynamically.

I have string representation of following snippet (getting from server):

```
columns: {
    id: {
      title: 'ID'
    },
    name: {
      title: 'Full Name'
    },
    username: {
      title: 'User Name'
    },
    email: {
      title: 'Email'
    }
  }
```

as far as my understanding settings is object in ng2 smart table and i have string representation of the same object.
How can i convert this string in valida javascript object.
Is there any other way to assing the settings property?

Answer (score 0):

Once you get the data from server you can parse the data to Java Script object in the following manner I am doing the same in my code which works for me.

```
settings = JSON.parse('{"columns":{"id":{"title":"ID","width":"100px"},"name":{"title":"Full Name","width":"40%"},"username":{"title":"User Name"},"email":{"title":"Email"}}}')
```

so you can parse the string representation of your data and parse it to be a Java Script object.